# mutableListOf(mutableListOf()) return an array of array with a size equal to 1 when it's first declared

Tags: arrays, kotlin

When I create a matrix (Array of Array) with the following declaration the returned size is 1 instead of 0 :

```
var matrix: MutableList<MutableList<Cell>> = mutableListOf(mutableListOf())
```

which lead to having a size equal to 2 when I add the first array to the matrix :

```
matrix.add(lineOfCells)
```

matrix now contain a first empty array at index 0 and `lineOfCells` array at index 1, but what I'm looking for is just to have `lineOfCells` at index 0.

Comment: Well, yes, since mutableListOf() creates and returns a List, and you're thus creatng a list containing a list. Just don't: `var matrix: MutableList<MutableList<Cell>> = mutableListOf()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an [0][0] cell, what looks like[[]] this, from the beginning so it means when you are adding one you have a second line of cells.
Or try
var matrix: MutableList> = mutableListOf()